# Eclipse, lambdas and Java 8 templates

Tags: eclipse, lambda, java-8, eclipse-mars

Is there a reason the Eclipse content assits doesn't work in/around lambdas? In a normal case Eclipse usually does this after writing a dot:

[image]

Which works just fine like anywhere else. However just a couple of lines later I get nothing:

[image]

Both objects are of the same type. Unfortunately I use these all the time as they make everything much faster and I don't understand why it works in one lambda and not the other.

Comment: No idea. Probably a bug in Eclipse. But what I can says is that you could use `Comparator.comparing(Person::getAge)` rather than `(Person a, Person b) -> a.age.compareTo(b.age)`

Comment: yeah, I forgot to mention I was just goofing around with lambdas and trying out different options, But thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Attempting an explanation (you asked for a *reason*): parsing lambda expressions in Java is a technical challenge, as the Java grammar was not made for parser generators. Code completion, OTOH, inevitably depends on parsing **incomplete** code, i.e., heuristics must be used to continue parsing after a syntax error. These two just don't nicely cooperate. As a result in some situations your incomplete code will look like garbage to the compiler and hence content assist is not able to figure out, what would be meaningful proposals.

The applied heuristics are constantly being improved. I recommend trying your examples on a [recent milestone build](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/index-developer.php). If the problem still exists, you might help the team by [filing a bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=JDT&component=Core) providing a code example, and describing your expectations and what actual behavior you observe.